# ng-click not firing in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use bootstrap tab with angularjs & have added ng-click to set active class on tab but its not happening, below is my code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" ng-class="{ 'active': tab === 1 }"><a href="#email" aria-controls="email" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="tab = 1">Email</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" ng-class="{ 'active': tab === 2 }"><a href="#phone" aria-controls="phone" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="tab = 2">Phone</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" ng-class="{ 'active': tab === 3 }"><a href="#username" aria-controls="username" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="tab = 3">Username</a></li>
    </ul>
```

tab's value is not changing and that's why the particular class is not getting applied.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `===` to `==`, it should works:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{ 'active': tab == 1 }"><a href="#email" aria-controls="email" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="tab = 1">Email</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{ 'active': tab == 2 }"><a href="#phone" aria-controls="phone" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="tab = 2">Phone</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{ 'active': tab == 3 }"><a href="#username" aria-controls="username" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="tab = 3">Username</a></li>
</ul>
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rsxgvqLw/).

Comment: Actually I have the router as well, so that #email, #phone is creating issue, its changing the route, so how I can disable it?

Comment: I think you should post another question for this problem (and we will need your JS file where you define your routes). :)

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, try to use

```
$scope.obj = { tab : 1};
```

and then in the view:

```
obj.tab
```

instead of just tab

Comment: still no luck, its same

Comment: When page reloads this check `ng-class="{ 'active': tab === 1 }"` works fine, but then onclick tab's value is not changing